# Date Key Expression in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to build a datekey in SSIS to Look like the following:

```
20161122
```

In that format, I am just wondering how this cant be done in SSIS expression builder using getdate?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `DATEPART` for this job. I believe the following formula will construct the format you seek:

`(DB_WSTR, 4)DATEPART("yy", GETDATE()) + (DB_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("month", GETDATE()) + (DB_WSTR, 2)DATEPART("dd", GETDATE())`

I did not try this formula, so you might need to amend it a bit. For example, taking care of leading zeros.

Comment: In SSIS 11.0.6615, I had to use "DT_WSTR" as opposed to "DB_WSTR".